# ¿Como mostrar datos con Vue-resource en Tabla Boostrap Vue?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Quiero mostrar solo algunos datos del siguiente json: https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10

En una tabla Boostrap-Vue se supone que tengo que exportar los datos pero no se muestra.

Mi código es el siguiente y solo quiero mostrar ciertos datos como el nombre y apellido.

```
<template lang="html">
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :personas="personas" :fields="fields"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Agenda',
  data () {
    return {
      fields: {
        last_name: {
          label: 'Person last name',
          sortable: true
        },
        first_name: {
          label: 'Person first name',
          sortable: true
        }
      },
      personas: []
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.obtenerAPI()
  },
  methods: {
    obtenerAPI () {
      this.$http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
        .then(function (respuesta) {
          this.personas = respuesta.body.results
          console.log(this.personas)
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
</style>
```

¿Como puedo mostrarlos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que los campos `first_name` y `last_name` no existen en el `JSON` devuelto por `randomuser`. En su lugar podemos encontrar `name.first` y `name.last`.

Para poder acceder a valores anidados podemos hacer uso de [`Scoped field slots`](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#scoped-field-slots) donde declaramos el `slot` igual al nombre del `field.key` y dentro de este agregar la expresion `data.item.*` para imprimir el valor deseado.

### Solución:

Podrías hacerlo así:

```
<template>
  <b-table :fields="fields" :items="personas">
    <template slot="first_name" slot-scope="data">
      {{data.item.name.first}}
    </template>
    <template slot="last_name" slot-scope="data">
      {{data.item.name.last}}
    </template>
  </b-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Agenda',
  data () {
    return {
      fields: [
        { key: 'first_name', label: 'Last Name' },
        { key: 'last_name', label: 'First Name' }
      ],
      personas: []
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.obtenerAPI()
  },
  methods: {
    obtenerAPI () {
      this.$http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
        .then(function (respuesta) {
          this.personas = respuesta.body.results
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

### Demo:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      fields: [
        { key: 'first_name', label: 'Last Name' },
        { key: 'last_name', label: 'First Name' }
      ],
      personas: []
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.obtenerAPI()
  },
  methods: {
    obtenerAPI () {
      this.$http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
        .then(function (respuesta) {
          this.personas = respuesta.body.results
        })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css">

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.5"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template>
    <b-table :fields="fields" :items="personas">
      <template slot="first_name" slot-scope="data">
        {{data.item.name.first}}
      </template>
      <template slot="last_name" slot-scope="data">
        {{data.item.name.last}}
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </template>
</div>
```